# MVC 5 Ajax form with field updates asynchronously and still supporting a Full form post

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

So I have been using MVC for a while but not a lot of Ajax. 
So the issue i have is that I have a create view where the first field of the create view is a Date picker which on change i want ajax to change the selection dropdown of another field on the form. I have the Ajax update working , but the form Post (Create button), now only calls into the Ajax method on the controller. I want the Ajax post back to call the default method Create method on the Controller. So the Create form contains 3 fields

1. A date (which has the OnChange Ajax submit)
2. A drop down list of id's and text
3. other fields as required

I have included the model and cshtml view files (one the partial). The controller is just simply a method taking either the datetime value or the entire model. 
So I have the code working where, when the date changes it updates the relevant LocalIds field, but because the 'create' button is inside the Ajax.BeginForm tags, when the create button is pressed, it generates an Ajax call, and I want it to generate a Form Post. What am i missing

CreateModel

```
public class IdsSelection
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Selections { get; set; }
}

public class CreateModel
{
    [Display(Name="Local Id's")]
    public IdsSelection LocalIds;
    [Display(Name="Day")]
    [Required, DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [Required, Display(Name = "Other Value")]
    [Range(1.0, 1000000.0, ErrorMessage ="Value must be greater than zero")]
    public decimal OtherValue { get; set; }

    public CreateModel()
    {
        Date = DateTime.Today;
    }
}
```

CreateView.cshtml

```
@Model Demo.Models.CreateModel
....
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ChangeDate", "Process", new AjaxOptions()
{
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    HttpMethod = "GET",
    UpdateTargetId = "changeid",
}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new
           {
               htmlAttributes = new
               {
                   autofocus = "autofocus",
                   @class = "form-control",
                   @Value = Model.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                   onchange = "$(this.form).submit();"
               }
           })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        @Html.Partial("_ShowIds", Model.LocalIds)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OtherValue, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OtherValue, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OtherValue, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
}
```

_ShowIds.cshtml

```
@model Demo.Models.IdsSelection

<div id="changeid" class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Local Id", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">

        @if(Model.Selections.Count == 1)        // one
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Selections[0].Text, new
            {
                htmlAttributes = new
                {
                    @class = "form-control",
                    @readonly = "readonly",
                }
            })
        }
        else            // more entries so show a dropdown
        {
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id, Model.Selections, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        }
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Use a normal form for the submit and use `jQuery.ajax` to call a separate server method that updates the DOM based on the selected date

Comment: Yeah that is the thing I don't understand. Is that a Javascript  call?

Comment: Yes. Remove the `onchange` event from you datepicker and add a script - `$('#Date').change(function() { // make ajax call to update the existing DOM });`

Comment: I did try this but the javascript didn't appear to be getting fired (on the date change)??? I even included jQuery script thinking I may not have had it

Comment: Did you see the answer I posted? And if its not firing, what errors are you seeing in the browser console?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the answer below when i last replied. I have since tried what you suggested and am getting a internal 500 error. The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'Date' of non-nullable type 'System.DateTime' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.PartialViewResult FetchLocalIds(System.DateTime)'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

Comment: That means the value your posting back is either `null` or not a valid date. In the script add `console.log($(this).val());` and inspect what is is

Comment: It's probably because I have my date in dd/MM/yyyy format. I'm thinking i will need to format as Mdy

Comment: The value your posting back needs to match the server culture so just test it by replacing `date: $(this).val()` with `date: '2015-01-01'` (i.e. ISO format which will always bind irrespective of the culture)

Comment: And I have just noticed you have `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}",ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]` on the property. It must be `{0:yyyy-MM-dd}` in order for the Chrome datepicker to work correctly. And you also need to remove `@Value = Model.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),` - under no circumstances should you ever attempt to overrride the `value` attribute. And are you also aware that `type="date"` is only supported in Chome (IE and FireFox will just display a standard textbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not shown you controller methods, but assuming the method which generates this view is named `Create()`, then create a corresponding POST method

```
[httpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateModel model)
```

for saving the data. The remove `@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ChangeDate", "Process", new AjaxOptions() { ..... ]))` and replace with a normal form to post back to the server (and you can remove `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js`)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    ....
```

Next create a controller method that returns your partial view based on the selected date

```
public PartialViewResult FetchLocalIds(DateTime date)
{
  IdsSelection model = // populate model based on selected date
  return PartialView("_ShowIds", model);
}
```

Next, in the view, wrap the current `@Html.Partial()` in a placeholder element

```
<div id="localids">
    @Html.Partial("_ShowIds", Model.LocalIds)
</div>
```

Then use jquery to handle the datepickers `.change()` event and call the `FetchLocalIds()` method to update the DOM using the `.load()` function.

```
$('#Date').change(function() {
  $('#localids').load('@Url.Action("FetchLocalIds")', { date: $(this).val() })
})
```

Note also to remove `onchange = "$(this.form).submit();"` from the `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new { ... })`